# Trying to condense javascript into for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I've got the following code that I am trying to condense to a **for loop** but am having no luck:

```
$("#motion1-sub1-1").hover( function () {
$("#motion1-sub1-1 div").show();
  }, 
  function () { $("#motion1-sub1-1 div").hide();
  }
);
$("#motion1-sub1-2").hover( function () {
$("#motion1-sub1-2 div").show();
  }, 
  function () { $("#motion1-sub1-2 div").hide();
  }
);
$("#motion1-sub1-3").hover( function () {
$("#motion1-sub1-3 div").show();
  }, 
  function () { $("#motion1-sub1-3 div").hide();
  }
);
$("#motion1-sub1-4").hover( function () {
$("#motion1-sub1-4 div").show();
  }, 
  function () { $("#motion1-sub1-4 div").hide();
  }
);
$("#motion1-sub1-5").hover( function () {
$("#motion1-sub1-5 div").show();
  }, 
  function () { $("#motion1-sub1-5 div").hide();
  }
);
```

Here's the **for loop** code that have to condense the above code:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
 $("motion1-sub1-" +  i).hover( function () { $("motion1-sub1-" +  i + "div").show();
  }, 
  function () { $("motion1-sub1-" +  i + "div").hide();
  }
);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your html? This should probably be solved with classes instead of id's and a for loop.

Comment: Your problem come from the fact you forgot the # and you're not using closures. so sub-5 will always be the one hiden/shown. but just look at @Tar answer, he has the right approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a for-loop, just bind to those elements that have a certain id pattern, and use `this` to reference them from within the hover functions:

```
$("[id^='motion1-sub1-']").hover(
    function(){
        $("div", this).show();
    },
    function(){
        $("div", this).hide();
    }
);
```

I don't know what type of element we're binding to, but you should provide that tag as part of the selector. For instance, if this is a `div` we're hovering, modify the selector to include that:

```
$("div[id^='motion1-sub1-']")
```

Or an even shorter, more DRY version:

```
$("[id^='motion1-sub1-']").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e){
    $("div", this).toggle( e.type === "mouseenter" );
});
```

Comment: This is very clever, but it seems like the wrong approach. Classes would be a better fit.

Comment: Thank you, this actually works very well. Not sure of any drawbacks as none seem to be presenting themselves.

Comment: @rod If this solved your problem, please consider accepting it. Also, unless prevented in some way, you should consider using a common class for each of these elements rather than numerous differing id values. It should save you some sanity in the future.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use a common class in this instance. I have other jquery stuff going on that is specific to each of these elements. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

How about giving all your divs a class of motion-sub and then doing

```
$(".motion-sub").hover(function() {
    $(this).show() }, function() { $(this).hide(); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a space on `motion1-sub1-x div` selector right before the `div`

```
 $("motion1-sub1-" +  i + " div")
```

Comment: I'm still missing something though as adding that missing space still doesn't make it work.